# The real tense of "I'm going to be talking about"

Tags: word-choice, future, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

I just listened to a video in which the speaker said "I'm going to be talking about....". Can we change that to "I'm going to talk about..."?

Comment: Why do you want to change what was said?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence

> [1.] "I'm going to be talking about...."

has a different meaning from

> [2.]  "I'm going to talk about..."

[1] and [2] differ in aspect (i.e. the internal temporal structure of the event). In [1] the speaker is focussing on the talking as an ongoing (continuous) event, whereas in [2] the focus is on the talking as a single, whole event.

Both forms are correct, and refer to the event in different ways. You could change from one to the other but you'd be talking in a slightly different way about the event.

Comment: Good! Glad to see somebody actually knows what they’re talking about around here.

Comment: In most cases, the difference between the two meanings is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 True, but we don't know what the case is here.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence in its current form conveys "My current state is such that I have not yet talked about [the topic] but can be expected to do so."

I'd suggest "I will talk about...".